# How to upload image from clipboard into sap.m.upload.UploadSet

Tags: sapui5

I received one required to upload clipboard image into UploadSet control. so basically when user click on 'From Clipboard' button the image which is present in clipboard must be added in UploadSet control.

[image]

So far I have achieve how to get image from clipboard (from [source](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/25/how-to-get-image-from-clipboard-in-sapui5-app/)) but I am stuck at how it could be attached to UploadSet control. furthermore I need to trigger clipboard when we click on button instead of windows paste event.

**Controller**

```
onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
        that.fnAttachFromClipboard(e);
    }, false);
},

fnAttachFromClipboard : function (oEvent) {
    var that = this;
    this.getImageFromClipboardAsBlob(oEvent)
        .then(function (sBase64) {
            // that.getView().getModel().setProperty("/imgSrc", sBase64);
        }.bind(this));
},

getImageFromClipboardAsBlob: function (pasteEvent) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let oUploader = this.getView().byId('tempUploadSet');
        if (pasteEvent.clipboardData && pasteEvent.clipboardData.items) {
            var aItems = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
                // Skip content if not image
                if (aItems[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue;
                // Retrieve image on clipboard as blob
                var oBlob = aItems[i].getAsFile();

                oUploader.addIncompleteItem(
                    new sap.m.upload.UploadSetItem({
                        fileName: oBlob.name,
                        uploadState: 'Ready',
                        mediaType: oBlob.type,
                        // url: sBase64data
                    })
                )
                resolve(oBlob);
            }
            reject("noImageInClipboard");
        } else {
            reject("noItemFound");
        }
    }.bind(this));
},

getImageFromClipboardAsBase64: function (pasteEvent) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let oUploader = this.getView().byId('tempUploadSet');
        if (pasteEvent.clipboardData && pasteEvent.clipboardData.items) {
            var aItems = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
            var bImageFound = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
                // Skip content if not image
                if (aItems[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                bImageFound = true;
                // Retrieve image on clipboard as blob
                var oBlob = aItems[i].getAsFile();
                var sFileName = oBlob.name;
                var sFileMediaType = oBlob.type;
                var oReader = new FileReader();
                oReader.readAsDataURL(oBlob);
                oReader.onloadend = function () {
                    var sBase64data = oReader.result;

                    oUploader.addIncompleteItem(
                        new sap.m.upload.UploadSetItem({
                            fileName: sFileName,
                            uploadState: 'Ready',
                            mediaType: sFileMediaType,
                            // url: sBase64data
                        })
                    )
                    resolve(sBase64data);
                }.bind(this);
            }
            if (!bImageFound) {
                reject("noImageInClipboard");
            }
        } else {
            reject("noItemFound");
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

**View**

```
<upload:UploadSet
    id="tempUploadSet"
    instantUpload="false"
    showIcons="false"
    uploadEnabled="true"
    terminationEnabled="true"
    multiple="true"
    uploadCompleted="onUploadComplete">
    <upload:toolbar>
        <OverflowToolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Button text="{i18n>action_from_clipboard}" type="Transparent" press="fnAttachFromClipboard" />
        </OverflowToolbar>
    </upload:toolbar>
</upload:UploadSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of analysis I found a (unethical) way, so thought to share in this forum.

> Warning: This is not an recommended way but you can refer only if there is a need that you must developed it (if unavoidable situation).

**Controller**

```
onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {                                    // Or Init - choice is yours
    window.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
        that.fnAttachFromClipboard(e);
    }, false);
},

fnAttachFromClipboard : function (oClipboardEvent) {
    if (oClipboardEvent.clipboardData === undefined) {
        MessageToast.show("No file attachment found in clipboard data");
    } else if (oClipboardEvent.clipboardData.items[0].type === 'image/jpeg' || oClipboardEvent.clipboardData.items[0].type === 'image/png') {          // If you want to attach only png or jpeg file extensions.
        this.getImageFromClipboardAsBlob(oClipboardEvent)
            .then(function (bSuccess) {
                MessageToast.show("Clipboard file added successfully");
            }.bind(this));
    } else {
        MessageToast.show("Clipboard image attachment upload feature only supported for jpeg and png file type");
    }
},

getImageFromClipboardAsBlob: function (pasteEvent) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let oUploader = this.getView().byId('tempUploadSet');
        if (pasteEvent.clipboardData && pasteEvent.clipboardData.items) {
            var aItems = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
                if (aItems[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue;    // Skip content if not image

                var oBlob = aItems[i].getAsFile();                      // Retrieve image on clipboard as blob

                oUploader.addIncompleteItem(
                    new sap.m.upload.UploadSetItem({
                        fileName: oBlob.name,
                        uploadState: 'Ready',
                        mediaType: oBlob.type
                    })
                )
                oUploader.getIncompleteItems()[i]._oFileObject = oBlob;         // Main logic to add blog file into control's private object
                // oUploader.getIncompleteItems()[i]._fFileSize = oBlob.size;
            }
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            reject("noItemFound");
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

That's it!

Hope someone could come up with proper implementation.